# "Position:absolute" not working in making div button stick to the bottom-right side of another div

Tags: html, css

**Just to give a brief background:** I have a modal which is called by a custom AngularJS directive in my page. I've been trying whole day to make the buttons in the modal stick to the right side of the div to no avail.

I've tried using position:absolute because that's what the other solutions here said, but it's not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class='readMore_title'>Welcome!</div></br>
    <div class='readMore_desc' style="padding:0px !important">
        <div class="question-content-wrapper">
        <div class="ng-modal-number-container">
            <div class="questionNumbers" ng-repeat="item in numberOfQuestions">
                <div class="questionNumberIcon" ng-style="item === currentQuestionIndex + 1 ? { 'background-color':'#455867', 'color': '#fff' } : {'background-color':'#fff', 'color': '#000 '}">{{item}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="padding-left:12px;padding-top:23px;word-wrap:break-word" ng-if="showWelcomeMessage">
        <p class="wizard-welcome-message">
            Click "Next" to begin.
        </p>

        <div class="carousel-wizard-btn-container">
            <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="wizardPrevious()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == 0">Previous</div>
            <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || wizardNext()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="showWelcomeMessage === true ? false : disableWizardFeatures()">Next</div>
            <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || showResults() " ng-show="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="disableWizardFeatures()">Finish</div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div style="word-wrap:break-word; padding-top:4px; padding-left:14px" ng-if="showWelcomeMessage === false ? true : false">
        <p class="wizard-question">
            <span style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Semibold'">Question {{currentQuestionIndex+1}}:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{currentQuestionObject.question}}
        </p>

        <ul style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div>
                <li ng-repeat="query in currentQuestionObject.choices" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <input class="TWInputField" name="{{currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" 
                   type="{{currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" id="{{query.id}}" 
                   ng-model="query.value" ng-change="changeOnSelection(query.value, query.id);choicesSelected = query.value"
                   ng-value="true">
                    <label for="{{query.id}}" style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular';font-size:17px;cursor:pointer">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{query.answer}}</label>
                </li>
                <p class="msg-required" ng-show="disableWizardFeatures()">Input is required.</p>

             <div class="carousel-wizard-btn-container">
                <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="wizardPrevious()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == 0">Previous</div>
                <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || wizardNext()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="showWelcomeMessage === true ? false : disableWizardFeatures()">Next</div>
                <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || showResults() " ng-show="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="disableWizardFeatures()">Finish</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.carousel-wizard-btn-container {
    /*right:5%;*/
    bottom:3%;
    position:relative; /* It's "relative" because "absolute" makes it overlap with the content text.*/
}

div.carousel-wizard-buttons {
    background-color:#01a982;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    width:110px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    bottom:100px;
    font-family:'MetricWeb-Bold';
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

This is how it currently looks like:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, as always (CSS is not really my forte, sadly...).

Thank you.

**Update 1:** Setting `carousel-wizard-btn-container`'s position to `absolute` returns this:

[image]

Setting the buttons to `float:right` returns this:

[image]

**Update 2:** Wrapped the buttons in another div as suggested by Arthur. Result is now this.

[image]

Almost there, except the buttons are outside the modal. :( I tried putting the div inside the one that wraps the questions to no avail:

```
<div style="word-wrap:break-word; padding-top:4px; padding-left:14px" ng-if="showWelcomeMessage === false ? true : false">
    <p class="wizard-question">
       <span style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Semibold'">Question {{currentQuestionIndex+1}}:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{currentQuestionObject.question}}
    </p>

    <ul style="padding-left:30px;">
        <div>
            <li ng-repeat="query in currentQuestionObject.choices" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                <input class="TWInputField" name="{{currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" 
                   type="{{currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" id="{{query.id}}" 
                   ng-model="query.value" ng-change="changeOnSelection(query.value, query.id);choicesSelected = query.value"
                   ng-value="true">
                <label for="{{query.id}}" style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular';font-size:17px;cursor:pointer">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{query.answer}}</label>
            </li>
             <p class="msg-required" ng-show="disableWizardFeatures()">Input is required.</p>
        </div>
    </ul>

    <div style="float:right">
        <div class="carousel-wizard-btn-container">
            <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="wizardPrevious()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == 0">Previous</div>
            <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || wizardNext()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="showWelcomeMessage === true ? false : disableWizardFeatures()">Next</div>
            <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || showResults() " ng-show="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="disableWizardFeatures()">Finish</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: position:absolute works best if it is inside a parent that has position:relative applied

Comment: The entire modal's already using position:relative. If I set the carousel-wizard-btn-container's position to absolute, it overlaps with the choices. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about float:right. If you could post a working example or link it will be easier, because maybe the issue is coming from elsewhere.

```
.carousel-wizard-buttons{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. `float:right` positioned the buttons outside the modal and made them stick so close to each other. The "Finish" button now comes first before "Previous". :(

Comment: can you wrap all three buttons in another div and then float that new div right?

Comment: Provide a link a jsfiddle

Comment: Hi Arthur, please see my edited question for the result.

Comment: `display: flex` did the trick. Just had to make a few tweaks with the button and choices' properties afterwards. Thank you Daniel!